# What is the idiomatic way that functional languages like Elixir handle large chains of processes?

Tags: functional-programming, elixir

Thinking of an example like a service/function that handles a customer checking out, there are many steps involved: server should (for example) check inventory, validate fraud, charge the credit card, deduct inventory, close the purchase, email the customer, notify the backend/handler/warehouse, and then return the http request.

In an object oriented language, I'd approach this problem one way by building a service object, and having it perform these steps synchronously and in order, branching when something goes wrong (maybe even use a state machine).

However, when I think of how I'd approach this problem in a language like Elixir, the only solution I can come up with is a long chain of pipes -- which feels like an anti-pattern in the Elixir world, especially when you consider branching.

The second thought I had was that each step is its own function (which feels idiomatic), and it takes an extra argument of the state of the purchase. In this case, the `validate_fraud` action could then call `charge_credit_card` with the `{purchase, fraud_passed}` information and then `charge_credit_card` would then call the next in the line when it was done. However, this would mean that each function needs to know it's place in a chain, which again feels like a smell (also each function would then need to have logic to handle the different incoming 'states').

**What is the idiomatic way in Elixir to handle a situation that the OO world would solve with a service object?**

Comment: One thing to consider is that a "service object" couples a lot of information into one piece of code.  That should also smell of an anti-pattern to you.

Comment: @OnorioCatenacci “service object” might delegate all ten checkers to different modules resulting in 12 lines of code, even if each `delegate` is granted with it’s own line.

Comment: A fair point.  It didn't sound as if he meant it that way though.

Answer (score 2):

The functional nature of the language cannot imply anything on business rules. If the chain looks like you’ve described, there is no value (and no possibility in fact) to make steps async, since `validate_fraud` does not make any sense before `inventory_check`, nor after `charge_credit`.

In such a case, the solution is very similar to the OO service: one would probably spawn a process ([`Task`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Task.html) in this particular case) that will pipe all steps:

```
task = Task.async(fn ->
   check inventory()
   |> validate fraud()
   |> charge()
   |> deduct_inventory()
   |> close_purchase()
   |> email_customer()
   |> notify_handler()
   |> return_http_request()
end)
```

Now tasks have a nice feature, one might check if it’s completed with [`Task.yield/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Task.html#yield/2), having it’s own timeout. The caller code might simply call `Task.await/2` to block the caller until the task is finished, or, better, it might wait for, say, 3 seconds with `Task.yield` and respond either with a result, if it’s finished, or with a “promise” if it takes longer to execute.